# MVC TextBox’s CSS properties does not work after a certain length

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```html
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SurveyName,new {@class = "textBoxProp" })
```

```css
    .textBoxProp{
        width:500px;
        height:35px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #000000;
        font-weight:normal;
    }
```

Effect is reflected when *width* is within *300px* but after that it has no effect.

Comment: Do you have an existing _Site.css_ file with `input, select, textarea { max-width: 280px; }`?

Comment: Thanks Jasen. I've override that property and worked.